# Copy files with specific pattern recursively

Tags: unix, recursion, copy

I want to copy recursively all files ending .pl

If I  `ls -R | grep -F .pl`

I can see all of them, however if I type any of the following commands I just get the *.pl files in the current directory

`cp -R *.pl`

`find . | ls  *.pl`

`ls -r | ls  *.pl`

`ls -R | grep -F .pl` (with this one I get only a few)

also if I want to scp copy with `scp -r  user@address:/directory/*.pl .`   I only get the files in the current directory

with `find . -name \*.pl` I don't get all of them, only a few files

How can I copy all files *.pl in all the subdirectories?

Comment: Seems a bit strange that you don't get all the files with find - I can't figure this one out without knowing your setup or which files are excluded.
Anyway, if you can list all the files using the ls + grep, I'd suggest piping these to xargs with the right copy command. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/ for examples of using xargs.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, I realised I was not waiting enough time to finish the command, I am new on linux. So the find command was actually showing all the files,  this command worked fine. 

    `find . -name \*.pl |cpio -pdv ../directory/`

the only thing I still don't know how to do is that all the files end up in a single directory without subdirectories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find path/to/dir -name "*.pl" -exec "cp" "{}" your/dest/dir ";"
```

**EDIT (2015/01/23):** Someone suggested (via an edit to this post) that on his shell it didn't work with the quotes and he had to remove them. I don't know which shell is that (:P) but it said it worked the following way:

```
find path/to/dir -name *.pl -exec cp {} your/dest/dir \;
```

Essentially, the quotes were to avoid the expansion of the asterisk to a list of files (which would happen automatically in bash if you had file with that extension in your current working directory), to avoid misinterpretation of the curly braces in some situations, and to avoid interpretation of the semicolon (`;`) which signals the end of the statement for bash (while we want it as an argument for find).

Comment: Is this command preserving subdirectory structures ? I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

This command works just fine with only a single SSH authentication required.

```
scp $(find . -name *.pl) $server_address:/destination/path/
```